# New Profile Edit Page using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a profile page in my project. 
I want to make a custom edit page...In which i can change password as well as user image and other stuffs using DEVISE gem.
How should i do this. All i have now is an edit button in my profile page.
I'm not so experienced in Ruby, so i have so many doubt regarding this.
1) Should i make a new html page for this?
2) How to update the password in controller?
3) Will it affect the signup page or anyother pages if i make changes in the default edit page  of Devise.

Pls Help

Comment: How is your profile set up in the models? Does it have its own model?

Comment: Profile doesnt have its own model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise just handles the authentication -- it doesn't care how you edit the attributes on its associated model, as long as its columns are present

> If you've added an image attribute, and other elements, to the `user`
>   model - you may wish to use something like [this tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password) to help
>   your users edit their respective attributes

I could give you some code if you want

Comment: If i write my own edit page what url should i give for form tag..
I mean should it point to a controler method where it will save the updated values to db or will all this gets saved automaticaly..

Comment: You should just use standard controller functionality - Devise handles authentication only; this is different

Comment: So in my new edit page. I have user name..password...password confirmation.. and image tag.. all input fields.. and how am i suppose update this in my database.. Saving directly wont save it in password hash ryt>?